# MySQL compute date of extended absences

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying de compute in a list of date of absence the complete date, including the extended absences. For example, the following list

```
2016-08-26 -> 2016-08-26;
2016-08-29 -> 2016-09-04;
2016-09-05 -> 2016-09-11;
2016-09-12 -> 2016-09-18;
```

should return : 
(2016-08-26 ; 2016-09-18)

The week-end doesn't count so : 
2016-08-26 -> 2016-08-26 to 2016-08-29 -> 2016-09-04 is extented 
(2016-08-26 is a friday)

I can't find an easy way to do it, and I also want to keep the others absence dates so I count the distinct and complete number of absences.

Here's the dataset I'm working on :

```
2016-02-10  2016-02-12;
2016-03-18  2016-03-18;
2016-03-29  2016-04-01;
2016-05-01  2016-05-13;
2016-06-15  2016-06-19;
2016-06-23  2016-06-24;
2016-08-05  2016-08-22;
2016-08-26  2016-08-26;
2016-08-29  2016-09-04;
2016-09-05  2016-09-11;
2016-09-12  2016-09-18;
2016-09-28  2016-09-30;
2016-10-24  2016-10-31;
2016-11-18  2016-11-18;
2016-11-21  2016-11-21;
2016-11-22  2016-11-22;
2016-12-09  2016-12-09;
2016-12-12  2016-12-12;
2016-12-20  2016-12-20;
2016-12-23  2016-12-23;
2016-12-26  2016-12-30;
```

Comment: What is the expected result of sample data?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this in pure MySql? I mean no other scripting language or anything can be used? What is your table structure? What kind of query are you using to get this data?

Comment: *I can't find an easy way to do it,* With respect, that's because it is a *hard* business problem to solve. When I write *hard business problem*, I mean it's a problem with many specification details and many special cases.

Comment: @Firze Only MySql, yes

Comment: @Firze This data are extracted from a table with this kind of structure : 
pers_id, begin_date, end_date